# shiny ggplot with interactive x and y does not pass information to brush

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, interactive

I am trying to create an interface where, after selecting the x and y variables from drop down menus, users can then observe the scatterplot, and select points using a brush. The data for those points would them display in the data table.
This works perfectly on a static plot, where the x and y variables don't change. But when the choice of x and y variables are the result of an input option, while the plot works as it should, the brush doesn't seem to read the data correctly.

It won't let me upload an image, but when you examine text output from the brush, the x and y values range from 0-1, when the actual values, that you can read off the axis labels, range from 0-7. So I am clearly not setting up the brush properly.
An error message appears in the datatable that says "Error: brushedPoints: not able to automatically infer "xvar" from brush

[image]

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
 column(4,selectInput("X_axis_Category",label="X axis Category",choices=as.list(colnames(scores_test)),selected="Ecological_Stress")        
),
column(4,selectInput("Y_axis_Category",label="Y axis Category",choices=as.list(colnames(scores_test)),selected="Ecological_Health")           
),
column(4,selectInput("Z_axis_Category",label="Z axis Category",choices=as.list(colnames(scores_test)),selected="Comprehensive_Score")
),

 column(12, plotOutput("plotui",brush=brushOpts("plot_brush",resetOnNew=T))),
 column(12,verbatimTextOutput("brush_info")),

wellPanel(width=9,h4("Points selected by brushing, with brushedPoints():"),dataTableOutput("plot_brushed_points"))
  )
)

server<-function(input,output){


  sample_scores=read.csv(file="D:\\GIS Projects\\TreesforTribs\\HUC12_Watershed_Scores.csv",sep=",")
dat<-sample_scores  
x_means<-reactive({
  mean(sample_scores[,input$X_axis_Category])
})
  y_means<-reactive({
    mean(sample_scores[,input$Y_axis_Category])

})
  x_var<-reactive({
      as.character(input$X_axis_Category)
    })

  y_var<-reactive({
    as.character(input$Y_axis_Category)
  })

  output$plotui= renderPlot({

     pc<-ggplot(sample_scores,aes_string(x=input$X_axis_Category,y=input$Y_axis_Category,size=input$Z_axis_Category,colour=input$Z_axis_Category))+ geom_point()+geom_vline(xintercept=x_means())+geom_hline(yintercept=y_means()) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(),size=guide_legend())

print (pc)
  })


   output$plot_brushed_points<-renderDataTable({
     res<-brushedPoints(dat,input$plot_brush)
       subset_res<-subset(res,select=c(HUC12,Ecological_Health,Ecological_Stress,Comprehensive_Score))
 print (subset_res)
   })

  output$brush_info<-renderPrint({

    cat("input$plot_brush:\n")
     str(input$plot_brush)
      })


    }
```

Comment: If possible, provide a reproducible code, including some sample data

Answer (score 4):

OK, I fixed it (isn't that just the way that as soon as you give in and ask for help- you find your stupid mistake?)

For the record, the brush option wasn't working because when I wrote my plot, I used "print".

```
output$plotui= renderPlot({

 pc<-ggplot(sample_scores,aes_string(x=input$X_axis_Category,y=input$Y_axis_Category,size=input$Z_axis_Category,colour=input$Z_axis_Category))
+ geom_point()+geom_vline(xintercept=x_means())+geom_hline(yintercept=y_means()) +guides(color=guide_legend(),size=guide_legend())

print (pc)
})
```

This created a plot that deceptively worked fine, except that the brush wasn't reading the x and y axis correctly.  When I removed the "print" and just called the plot, the brush worked the way I wanted it to.

```
output$plotui= renderPlot({     
pc<-ggplot(sample_scores,aes_string(x=input$X_axis_Category,y=input$Y_axis_Category,size=input$Z_axis_Category,colour=input$Z_axis_Category))
+ geom_point()+geom_vline(xintercept=x_means())+geom_hline(yintercept=y_means()) +guides(color=guide_legend(),size=guide_legend())
#print (pc) ELIMINTATE THE PRINT OPTION
pc
})
```